# WordPress site not throwing 404 for invalid URLs | Nginx - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nginx, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I've set up a LEMP environment on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine, following the [How To Install WordPress with LEMP on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial on DigitalOcean's community archive. All works great, except for when navigating to page that doesn't exist (e.g: `https://www.example.com/page-that-doesnt-exist/`), it returns a 200 and renders the homepage (without a 301 redirect), instead of returning a 404. However, when navigating to a page under the `/blog/` scope that doesn't exist, then a 404 is returned as you'd expect (e.g: `https://www.example.com/blog/post-that-doesnt-exist/`).

This wouldn't be intended WordPress behaviour, right?

Below is the Nginx configuration used:

```
# Virtual Host configuration for www.example.com

# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.

server { # Redirect http:// to https://
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.au/ssl-bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/example.com.key;

        root /var/www/www.example.com;

        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
        location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Comment: No, that's not normal. But it's also not usually a problem with nginx. And your config looks fine. Disable all your plugins and switch to a default theme.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've tried disabling all the plugins, and switching back to a clean installation of the Twenty Nineteen theme, and no improvement. Would there be anything else I could test? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The nginx configuration shared by you doesn't have any problem. Please check the wordpress configuration once for the 404 page settings.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't see any settings specific to the handling of 404 errors in the WordPress options. Is there a set of settings in particular you have in mind? Thanks again.